# how can i find out the size of each individual columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Do we have a query to find out the size of each mysql columns. This way we can tell which columns are empty and which or not.
I could not find any useful information on internet.

Comment: What do you mean by the size of a column?

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of each column? Will this only include unique values, or all rows that contain something?

Comment: @Barmar, let me be clear here. When you take mysql database size, you can tell the DB/table_schema size of  information_schema, performace_schema, mysql etc. In similar fashion, can we check the size of individual columns?

Comment: @tshimkus, all rows that contain something or nothing.

Comment: You mean the total amount of data in that column in all rows of the table?

Comment: Barmar, that is correct.

Comment: I don't think this statistic is maintained automatically anywhere. InnoDB doesn't even keep the number of rows up to date.

Comment: So you need to calculate it yourself. For variable-length datatypes like `VARCHAR`, you need to add up the length in all rows, plus add in the length overhead.

Comment: For fixed-size types like `INT`, you just multiply the number of rows by the size of the datatype.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I just needed to know if there is a way. The reason i asked is because, if i have huge set of tables in any schema, i need to know which tables are empty and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a detailed answer in this post https://www.tecmint.com/check-mysql-database-size-in-linux/